# Google sheets query across multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have data in two sheets relating to students in year groups.

In 'pastoral tracker' I have a single cell, A2 and a user selects a year group between "Year 7" to "Year 11".
In Col B, I want my query to list the names of all of the students who are in that year.

My data is in a second sheets called 'names'.
Col A contains the names of every student in the school and col B contains the year they are in:

'John Kennedy', 'Year 7'
'Frank Sinatra', 'Year 8'
etc.

I have tried this query

```
=query({'pastoral tracker'!A2,names!A1:B},"SELECT * WHERE col3 = col1")
```

I am presuming that the {} concatenates the data across all of the sheets which is why I am querying col1 against col3.

No joy so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if this works:

```
=query(names!A1:B,"WHERE B = '"&'pastoral tracker'!A2&"'", 1)
```